# Determine Critical points in optimisation problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

So I have this problem where I am supposed to calculate the max and min value of a function
$f(x,y)=x+2y$ restricted by the disk $x^2+y^2\le 1 $.

I have calculated the $df/dx $ and $df/dy$ and they are both constant so $f$ does not have any critical points, meaning the max and min must exist on the boundary points of the domain (that is $x^2+y^2=1$).

I then parameterize the disk to $x=\cos t$, and $y=\sin t$ which gives us 
$f(x,y)=\cos t+2\sin t=g(t)$
Critical points of $g$ -> $g'(t)=0=-\sin t+2\cos t$ -> $\sin t/\cos t=2$ -> $\tan t=2$.

Where do I go from here? The book says $x=\pm 1/\sqrt 5$, and $y=\pm 2/\sqrt 5$, but I have no clue how to get there from $\tan t = 2$

Comment: You have $\tan t = 2$, then $\frac{y}{x} = 2$. From this and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, you  got the result.

Comment: I am so blind.. Thank you so much, wish i could accept this as solution. How do I close the question without picking an accepted answer?